# How to mock specific function in object using Jest?

Tags: mocking, tdd, reactjs, jestjs, refluxjs

I'm testing a React/Reflux application using Jest. I have the following function in a store:

```js
onLoad: function() {
  console.log("ORIGINAL LOAD");
  // http request here
}
```

I'm trying to mock it out so that it just does what it needs to do without doing the actual network stuff:

```js
beforeEach(function() {

  // mock out onLoad so instead of making API call the store gets test data
  PostStore.onLoad = jest.genMockFunction().mockImplementation(function () {
    var p1 = new Post(
      "54da7df5119025513400000a",                    // id
      "Test Post",                                   // title
      "Kji6ftLjUqhElgnqOBqMUKxYONpU7nK/cu6jTA==\n",  // owner anonId
      "Test Course 1",                               // course name
      "This is a test!",                             // content
      6,                                             // upvotes
      2,                                             // downvotes
      ["Kji6ftLjUqhElgnqOBqMUKxYONpU7nK/cu6jTA==\n"] // voter anonIds
    );

    this.posts = [p1];
    console.log("mocked function");
  });

  // component initialized here
});
```

However, it seems like the mocked function never even gets created. When I run the tests, the console still logs `ORIGINAL LOAD`.

What's the correct way to override the object's method so that instead of setting the `posts` array in `PostStore` by doing an ajax call it just sets it with test data?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm having a very similar issue, but I'm testing with Jasmine and injecting dependencies using Rewire. I've logged an issue on the Reflux GitHub repo: https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs/issues/300

Comment: I never resolved it, but for Jasmine I recommend using Sinon to mock things out.

Comment: thanks, it turned out to be a limitation of Rewire, injecting the dependency after Reflux's store mixin was loaded. I ended up going with [inject-loader](https://github.com/plasticine/inject-loader) for webpack

Comment: Are you doing var PostStore = require('PostStore') before you actually use PostStore in your test? I believe you'll have to define your mockImplementation after the require statement to ensure that the jest auto mocking doesn't overwrite your mockImplementation.

Comment: I'm not sure if I was. I rewrote it using just rails instead.

Answer (score 6):

I have found jest mock instance function
[It's here](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#mockfn-mockimplementation-fn)

eg:

```js
import expect from 'expect';

jest.mock('../libs/utils/Master');
import Master from '../libs/utils/Master';

Master.mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    returnOne: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(1)
  }
})
describe('test Master', function() {
  it('test search', function() {
    let master = new Master();
    expect(master.returnOne()).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Almost there, all you need to do is

```
const onLoad = jest.fn().mockImplementation(function () {
    var p1 = new Post();//Add your stuff here
    this.posts = [p1];
    console.log("mocked function");
  });
PostStore.onLoad = onLoad.bind(PostStore); //PostStore is your object.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the global `fetch` and overwrite it with a mock, which will then be picked up by code in the executed tests.

```
const globalFetch = global.fetch;
const mockFetch = jest.fn() as jest.MockedFunction<typeof fetch>;

global.fetch = mockFetch;

afterAll(() => {
  global.fetch = globalFetch;
});
```