# Jest mock class instance function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have a scenario that seems pretty straight forward but I'm not able to find an example in the doc that does what I need. I've searched SO also but haven't found anything apparently...

I want to mock a function from a class that is initialised and used inside the function I'm actually testing.

Here's an example:

```
// helpers.js
import API from './api'

export const validateUsername = async (username) => {
  const myApi = new API()
  try {
    await myApi.validate(username)
    return 'valid'
  } catch (e) {
    return 'invalid'
  }
}
```

In my test, I want to mock `myApi.validate` to make it return a valid response or throw. But for some reason I can't find the way to do it.

```
// helpers-test.js
it('returns "invalid" if the username is invalid', async () => {
  // here I need to mock myApi.validate to return or throw
})
```

I'm really not sure why I haven't figured this out yet, seems pretty common to do right?

Anyone?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594388/how-to-mock-specific-function-in-object-using-jest

Comment: ah thanks it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out thanks to @Volodymyr.

I think my main issue was to import the lib *before* mocking it.

```
jest.mock('path/to/api')
import {Api} from 'path/to/api'

const validateMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {...})
Api.prototype.validate = validateMock

// now it works
```